# WCF to read file sent in base64 format

Tags: c#, wcf, base64

I have a WCF api method UploadDocument which is accepting file content in base64 format in a json string.

The method can have at-most 3 files sent to it from the client. While testing I found out that when sending multiple files i.e if file size is large, the method is not called at all and the client gets a bad request error.

I am testing it in [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/). I also tested it by creating a test application in C#. Do I need to change something in web.config?

I read up on the net I tried adding this in WCF web.cofig

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="IncreasedTimeout" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967296" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

What can be the issue?

**Update:**
Web.config contents:

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967296" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00">
          <readerQuotas
      maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Have you added WCF Tracing?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx
Follow the instructions on the above link, to add tracing, post your errors here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the maxStringContentLength attribute of the readerQuotas element. See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you post an example of your binding with the readerQuotas you are using?

Comment: I think i see the problem now, you are using transferMode="Streamed", which requires a specific implementation of your service. I expect transferMode="Buffered" will solve your problems.

If you still like to use streamed see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "The streaming mode is useful when the information that is passed is lengthy and can be processed serially. Streaming mode is also useful when the message is too large to be entirely buffered." Since my method is sending a lengthy message I am using Streaming mode.